# How to print N identical characters

Tags: c++, string

There is such a program

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    const int n = 15;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout << string(n/2-1-i, ' ') << string(i*2+1, 42) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But in the process, it throws an exception. What are the ways to get rid of it or to write a program on another.

```
      *
     ***
    *****
   *******
  *********
 ***********
*************
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_create
```

Comment: You are trying to pass a negative number as the string's size. `15/2-1-7` is `-1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`n/2-1-i` will be negative when `n=15` and `i >= 7`, because `n/2 == 7`. So a redesign is needed for your program.

**EDIT:**

Just one line to change:

```
   cout << string(n-i-1, ' ') << string(i*2+1, 42) << endl;
```